# post method with bearer auth in dio in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, post, dio

I tried to make post method with Bearer Auth in dio but I got Http status error [500]

this is my code

```
sendData() async {
  pr.show();

if (_value == null) {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0)).then((value) {
    setState(() {
      pr.hide();

      utils.showAlertDialog(
          select_area, "warning", AlertType.warning, _scaffoldKey, true);
    });
  });

  return;
}

// Get info for attendance
var dataKey = getKey;
var dataQuery = getQuery;
var userToken = getToken;

// Add data to map
Map<String, dynamic> body = {
  'key': dataKey,
  'worker_id': getId,
  'q': dataQuery,
  'lat': _currentPosition.latitude,
  'longt': _currentPosition.longitude,
  'area_id': _value,
};

// Sending the data to server
final uri = utils.getRealUrl(getUrl, getPath);
Dio dio = Dio();
Map<String, String> mainheader = {
  "Content-type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": userToken,
};
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(body);
final response = await dio.post(uri,
    data: formData, options: Options(headers: mainheader));

var data = response.data;
```

and also see this image , I can see the token in my function , so what can I do to fix it
[image: image of the error]

I tried this code but also same

```
dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
dio.options.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer userToken";
```

Update -----

this is the details of the 500 error

[image: details of 500 error]

as you see its same error when I make the post without auth in postman so I think the problem its from headers

[image: without auth]

and here with auth

[image: with auth]

Comment: See https://pub.dev/packages/dio#handling-errors to find out more about the error. Also if it is Bearer token server expects, the correct format is  "Bearer $userToken".

Comment: i make this format and not working same issue

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error is a server-side error.

You should be able to find the cause of the problem on the server.

Comment: yes I know , and the error because they can't reach one field in users CRUD , I tried in postman without headers I got same error but with headers its work

Comment: I add it so you can see

Comment: So, isn't it done? What is your question?

Comment: I add the auth as bearer token but as you see I still get that error